# Fluent Nhibernate and quartz error configuration section not found in application configuration file

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, quartz.net

```
2015-06-22 11:23:01,427 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment..cctor(:0) - NHibernate 4.0.0.GA (assembly 4.0.0.4000)
2015-06-22 11:23:01,458 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.LoadGlobalPropertiesFromAppConfig(:0) - hibernate-configuration se
ction not found in application configuration file
2015-06-22 11:23:01,474 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BuildBytecodeProvider(:0) - Bytecode provider name : lcg
2015-06-22 11:23:01,474 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.get_Properties(:0) - Using reflection optimizer
Control+C detected, attempting to stop service.
```

I am using Fluent to configure Nhibernate

```
  // Returns our database configuration
        private static MsSqlConfiguration DbConfig()
        {
            return MsSqlConfiguration
                .MsSql2008
                .Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>()
                .ShowSql()
                .DefaultSchema("dbo")
                .ConnectionString(DBUtil.DBConnString);
        }
```

All dlls and config Files are placed in same folder there is a job which uses Nhibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was with my Connection String in the Quartz.server.exe, the name was different with the name used in fluent DbConfig method. Updating the name of connection string fixed the issue.